# How can I find lattice points of a circle sector?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I have a 10x10 grid, and I'd like to find how many lattice points are inside a sector of a circle of any angle.

**Circle details**

- Radius: 5
- Center: (0, 0)
- Sector 1: 65 degrees
- Sector 2: 300 degrees

How do I find how many integer points are inside each of those sectors?

Comment: Make a sketch and count them. For 65 degrees, I get from 14 to 17 depending on the attitude of the sector. That is assuming you are counting the lattice points on the boundary of the sector as well as those in the interior. Did you intend to restrict the positions of the sectors by, for example, requiring that one edge be on the x-axis?

Comment: Sorry, I should be more clear. I want to program a method to find the lattice points given the grid, the radius, and the angle of each sector. The edges of the sector could fall anywhere in the circle, not necessarily on either x or y axis.